# How to properly split a vector into components?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

In the following diagram , consider the incline to be frictionless , here
along line L1 and L2

R = mg cos$\theta$ and

R cos$\theta$ =mg

Clearly both these equations cannot be true simultaneously in all cases .

What is the mistake in this that resulted into this error?[image]

Comment: How do you take them to be equal? They don't have to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the mistake in this that resulted into this error?

The mistake is to assume them equal in both cases. You are essentially assuming that the forces must cancel out and sum up to zero in any direction. But you forget that there is acceleration happening as well - and then forces do *not* cancel out.

- In the **perpendicular** direction there is indeed no acceleration. So Newton's 1st law agrees with you:
  $$\sum F=0=R-mg\cos(\theta)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad R=mg\cos(\theta)$$
- In the **vertical** direction, there *is* acceleration (the block accelerates down the incline and there is thus a vertical acceleration component $a_v$). Newton's 2nd law says:
  $$\sum F=ma_v=R\cos(\theta)-mg\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad R\cos(\theta)=mg+ma_v$$

Answer (score 1):

$R = mg \cos\theta$ comes from

$F=ma \Rightarrow R - mg \cos\theta =m\,0$

looking at motion perpendicular to the slope where the acceleration perpendicular to the slope is zero.

$R \cos\theta \ne mg$ because if one looks at vertical motion

$F=ma \Rightarrow R - mg \cos\theta =m\,a_{\rm vertical}$

and $a_{\rm vertical}$ is not zero.